# Need to hide navigation menu at editing documents in office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, edit

In our system we are using documents such as Excel, Word, etc., and when we edit them online a menu appears on the top left showing other products that will not use at the moment, and we need to hide it

[image]

In box.com when you edit office documents that menu is hidden, wich is exactly what we want to do, does anyone know how?

[image]

We appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can't Hide **Main ribbon** or **Box menu** within it of **Office 365**. You can only customize specific application's(eg. Word/Excel/PowerPoint) ribbon [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-or-turn-on-the-ribbon-4dce2753-6ccc-4fb2-bec2-44c24fea4999)

Comment: Thanks for your help, the instructions are for Office365 offline version, and can't find the same options for online version